# Form based on associative array symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form like this :

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->createBuilder(FormType::class, $user)
            ->add('planningday', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Sélectionnez un jour',
                'choices' => array(
                    'Lundi' => 1,
                    'Mardi' => 2,
                    'Mercredi' => 3,
                    'Jeudi' => 4,
                    'Vendredi' => 5
                )
            ))
            ->add('planningcontent', TextType::class, array( 'label' => 'Description'))
            ->add('S\'inscrire au planning', SubmitType::class)
            ->getForm();
```

I want to disable some select value based on an associative array :

```
array (size=5)
  1 => boolean true
  2 => boolean false
  3 => boolean false
  4 => boolean false
  5 => boolean false
```

How can i use my associative array to put value inside my form ?

I'd like to pass something like required = true/false based on the associative array

Comment: Do you mean disable the day choices?

Comment: No i just want to disabled some day. In my associative array if 1 => true, it's because monday is taken by some user. So i want to disabled the monday day just to make sure nobody will take it.

Comment: You need to figure out where you are going to store those user choices; maybe you plan to store in an Entity or maybe in cookies or sessions? This is not a `form` issue!